# How to pause a thread in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

Consider the following code:

> while(true) {
>       someFunction();
>       Thread.sleep(1000);
>   }

What I want is that, someFunction() be called once every 10 seconds. But this is not the case. It is being called every second. I tried Thread.wait(1000), but even that doesnt help. I removed of the while part, just kept the body, and at the end wrote :

> Thread.start();

But it throwed an exception. Is there any other solution to this?

Comment: How many milliseconds do you think are in a second?

(Hint: It's not 100)

Comment: lol. My bad. Didnt realise I was putting 1000 and not 10000!! :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's being called every second because you're sleeping for 1000 milliseconds, aka 1 second.

Change it to `Thread.sleep(10000)` and that'll be better for you.

Alternatively, use

```
Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10));
```

which means you don't have to do the arithmetic yourself. (Many APIs now take a quantity and a `TimeUnit`, but there doesn't appear to be anything like that for `Thread.sleep` unfortunately.)

Note that this will make the thread unresponsive for 10 seconds, with no clean way of telling it to wake up (e.g. because you want to shut it down). I generally prefer to use `wait()` so that I can pulse the same monitor from a different thread to indicate "I want you to wake up now!" This is usually from within a while loop of the form

```
while (!shouldStop())
```

EDIT: tvanfosson's solution of using a `Timer` is also good - and another alternative is to use [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) which can be a bit more flexible (and easier to test).

Comment: @Jon, are we sure that mithun1538 is using ThreadPool at all?

Comment: ThreadPool? I havent heard that term before. I am developing a simple application, so I am guessing that I am not using "ThreadPool".

Comment: There is http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#sleep(long\) , although maybe that's not very SoC. Also, the thread could be woken up with an interrupt.

Answer (score 3):

`Thread.sleep()` takes the number of miliseconds to sleep. Thus, calling `Thread.sleep(1000)` sleeps 1000 miliseconds, which is 1 second. Make that `Thread.sleep(10000)` and it will sleep 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want to do is use a `Timer` and set up a scheduled invocation of the function rather than sleeping.  If you need more exactness with regard to the interval, you can keep track of how long it has been since the last run and adjust the new timer to keep your interval from drifting.   See an example of a simple timer in this [tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/TimerScheduleataskthatexecutesonceeverysecond.htm).

I won't go into detail about the issue with regard to the precision of the argument, since @Jon has already covered that -- you need milliseconds rather than seconds.

Answer (score 1):

1 second is 1000 milliseconds, so if you want 10 seconds = 10 * 1000 = 10000 milliseconds

e.g.

```
try { 
     long numMillisecondsToSleep = 5000; // 5 seconds 
     Thread.sleep(numMillisecondsToSleep); 
} catch (InterruptedException e) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider 1000 milliseconds is 1 second. For that you should use Thread.sleep(10000) for acheiving pause your thread in 10 seconds. You can also use looping with how many seconds to wait your thread.
Ex. suppose you want to pause your thread in half-an-hour( 30 minutes). Then use,

```
for(i=0;i<1800;i++)
{
   Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

It will pause your thread in 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

## `Duration`

Pass a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) object to the [`sleep`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(java.time.Duration)) method, in Java 19+. More convenient than calculating a number of milliseconds.

```
Thread.sleep( Duration.ofSeconds( 10 ) )
```

Answer (score -2):

> What I want is that, someFunction() be
>   called once every 10 seconds.

Then why do you call `Thread.sleep()` with 1000 as parameter? That's in milliseconds, so you're explicitly saying "wait 1 second".